# UnboundLocalError when submitting form in Django App

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am trying to submit a form but receiving an error:

UnboundLocalError at /create/
local variable 'spr' referenced before assignment

Below is the section of my views.py file that is highlighted in the error, specifically:

`return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %spr.id)`

```
def create(response):
if response.method == "POST":
    form = CreateNewSprint(response.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
        spr = Sprint(name=n)
        spr.save()
        response.user.sprint.add(spr)

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %spr.id)

else:
    form = CreateNewSprint()
return render(response, "main/create.html", {"form": form})
```

I am unsure of why this is happening, any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. If any other code/information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If the `form.is_valid()` returns `False`, then it will aim to evaluate `return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %spr.id)`, but `spr` is never set in that case. You thus should in that case rerender the invalid form:

```
def create(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateNewSprint(response.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            n = form.cleaned_data['name']
            spr = Sprint(name=n)
            spr.save()
            response.user.sprint.add(spr)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/%i' %spr.id)

    else:
        form = CreateNewSprint()
    return render(response, 'main/create.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and
> determine the url based on the view name and the parameters. This is more safe and elegant than performing string formatting and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).

Comment: I have tried to emulate the above but unfortunately when trying to submit, a new sprint is not created. Have I missed something/done something incorrectly?

Comment: @G.Hines: of course it will not create a new `Sprint`, since the form you have submitted is invalid. If you render the form with `{{ form }}` it will display the errors on the form. You can also `print(form.errors)` to check the errors in the view.

Comment: Ah okay of course, that makes sense. Thank you for helping me to understand!